# Function in python to find the uppercase characters from a sum of ascii numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I'm trying to write a function to find the text from a sum of ascii numbers. All characters are uppercase , and if for example I get 155 , the function need to return AZ (65+90). Think of it like columns in an Excel table: it goes from A to Z, then AA, AB...AZ, BA, BB and etc. It needs to work for up to 4 digits. I'm trying a recursive function, but it has some errors. If I give the function 270 -> it return `AAAK`, not `ZZZ` , because I check if `65(A)` fits in that `number`, then I go to the next if it doesn't (with the second if: `number % asc + asc`). Another error is in the output of the code: `130+90` works well , `AAZ`, but if I add 1 it should give me `ABA`. In these cases I think I'm doing things wrong the most. Initially I wanted to use integer division (`//`) and modulo (`%`), but it didn't work.

```
def ascii(number):
    result = ""
    if number > 90:
        for asc in range(65, 91):
            if number % asc + asc in range(65, 91):
                result += chr(asc)
                result += ascii(number - asc)
                break
    else:
        result += chr(number)

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = ""
    print(ascii(131))
    print(ascii(130+90))
    print(ascii(130+90+1))
    print(ascii(130+90+39))

#output: AB, AAZ, BAZ, UTZ
```

Comment: And how to differentiate between `155 = AZ` and the same `155 = ZA`?

Comment: I don't really know ... I got this problem from a guy at work and I cant discuss with him now

Answer (score 0):

Searching recursively is fine, the problem is that you don't set a limit to how deep it need to go, that is why for 270 it goes 4 levels to AAAK and not 3 to ZZZ.

So first we need to determine how deep we need to go, then the base case for the recursive function now become: in the base level return the character if the value is correct otherwise return nothing, and for the rest, for each character, we check if we get a result from the recursive case, if we do we're done otherwise we continue and if no match simple return nothing.

Something like

```
import itertools
A = ord("A")
Z = ord("Z")

def length(num):
    if num < A:
        return 0
    for n in itertools.count(1):
        if A*n <= num <= Z*n:
            return n
        elif num <= A*n:
            break
    return 0

def search_ascii(num, level):
    if level<1:
        return ""
    if level==1:
        if A <= num <= Z:
            return chr(num)
        return ""
    for n in range(A,1+Z):
        r = search_ascii(num-n,level-1)
        if r:
            return chr(n)+r
    return ""
    

def to_ascii(num):
    n = length(num)
    if not n:
        raise ValueError("value too small")
    return search_ascii(num,n)


print(to_ascii(131))
print(to_ascii(130+90))
print(to_ascii(130+90+1))
print(to_ascii(130+90+39))
print(to_ascii(270))
print(to_ascii(155))
```

and the output

```
AB
AAZ
ABZ
OZZ
ZZZ
AZ
```

the non-recursive version can be done with itertools.product like so:

```
def to_ascii_it(num):
    n = length(num)
    if not n:
        raise ValueError("value too small")
    for chars in itertools.product(range(A,1+Z), repeat=n):
        if sum(chars)==num:
            return "".join(map(chr,chars))
```